# error: cannot find Chrome binary - Selenium OSX java Eclipse

Tags: java, macos, selenium, binary, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to launch Chrome using Selenium. I was able to apply this same code (with minor changes) to Firefox, but for some reason Chrome is not working.
It says it can't find the Chrome binary, but I have the chromedriver correctly linked to its file source.

Feedback anyone?

Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class scociatest1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/theone/Downloads/chromedriver-2");

        // Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //Launch the Scocia Demo Website
        driver.get("https://apps.scotiabank.com/LEAP_Prototype/desktop/html/Chile_index.html#");

        // Print a Log In message to the screen
        System.out.println("Successfully opened the website");
    }
}
```

Error Details:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4) on port 33806
>   Only local connections are allowed.
>   Nov 24, 2016 4:14:02 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
>   Nov 24, 2016 4:14:03 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
>   System info: host: 'Thes-MacBook-Air.local', ip: '10.0.9.17', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{message=unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64), platform=ANY}]
>   Session ID: ede6a5a0ba4b5c7b2734be4418af439e
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
>       at com.scocia.test.scociatest1.main(scociatest1.java:16)

Comment: The driver seems to be linked up just fine as it is the one reporting the error - and the problem it is describing is that it cannot find the Chrome binary - as in the browser itself. Maybe Chrome is not installed in the default location? https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be running your test from a Windows machine. Then your chromedriver should be an exe file --> "/Users/theone/Downloads/chromedriver-2.exe". After that, if it still doesn't work, you can check with an absolute path.

Comment: How exactly does a stacktrace clearly mentioning the platform is Mac OS/X and a tag saying it is OSX make you say it is running on a Windows machine?

Comment: My bad, I was too focused on the similarity with a problem I had faced before.